# A Mellin Integrals, related to Conformal Field theory.

Tags: integration

[ Note : I had originally asked this question in math.stackexchange.com but since there was no response, I am reposting here. I don't know if I am violating any rules of Physics Stackexchange, if so please comment what is the better way of posting it here. I think Physics community would also be helpful in this particular question. ]

I know that, $$ \int_{-i \infty}^{i \infty} \dfrac{ds}{2\pi i} \int_0^\infty d a a^{s - k - 1} = \int_{-i \infty}^{i \infty} \dfrac{ds}{2\pi i} \delta(s - k) $$.

I want to find the following integral $$ \int_{-i \infty}^{i \infty} \dfrac{ds}{2\pi i} \int_0^\infty da \dfrac{ a^{s - k - 1}}{a+c} $$ where $c$ is a constant.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Denote $w=-i(s-k)$, change variable to $a=e^{t}$ to get the integral $$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}dt \frac{e^{iwt}}{e^t+c}.$$ This is a Fourier transform of $$\frac{1}{e^t+c}.$$

It will contain a Dirac delta, because this function tends to the constant $1/c$ as $t\to-\infty$. Another function with this property is $\theta(-t)/c$, where $\theta$ is the step function (0 for negative argument and 1 for positive). We can then write
$$
\frac{1}{e^t+c}=\left[\frac{1}{e^t+c}-\frac{\theta(-t)}{c}\right]+\frac{\theta(-t)}{c}.
$$
Fourier transform of $\frac{\theta(-t)}{c}$ is
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}dt \frac{\theta(-t)}{c}e^{iwt}=-\frac{i}{cw}+\frac{\pi}{c}\delta(w).
$$
On the other hand, the function
$$
f(t)=\frac{1}{e^t+c}-\frac{\theta(-t)}{c}
$$
decays exponentially in both directions, and we have
$$
I=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}dt e^{iwt}f(t)=\int_0^{+\infty}dt\frac{e^{iwt}}{e^t+c}-\int_0^{+\infty}\frac{dt}{c}\frac{e^{-iwt-t}}{e^{-t}+c},
$$
where the both integrals are well-convergent. We can find using e.g. Mathematica
$$
I=\frac{{}_2F_1(1,1+k-s;2+k-s;-c)}{1+k-s}-\frac{{}_2F_1(1,1+s-k;2+s-k;-c^{-1})}{c^2(1+s-k)},
$$
where we might need to take some analytic continuations to make sense of these expressions. I am also not sure whether this is the simplest form for these integrals.

Getting back to the original integral, we have
$$
\int_0^\infty da\frac{a^{s-k-1}}{a+c}=\frac{\pi}{c}\delta(s-k)+\frac{1}{c(s-k)}+I
$$

Comment: Let me see if this is helpful, I have to find a way to integrate I in your answer and see if it has any poles. Once I confirm, I'll accept your answer. Thanks!